# How do class attributes and instance attributes differ in Django models?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following models **(Here, we are using a class attribute)**:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    ...

    def some_function(self, some_condition):
        if some_condition:
            # Do something

class Bar(models.Model):
    ...
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo)

    _some_condition = False # Class attribute

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Do something that sets the `_some_condition` class 
        # attribute based on some conditions
        self.foo.some_function(self._some_condition)
        super(Bar, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

In short, my `Bar` class has a class attribute called `_some_condition`. This is set in the save function, and then used to call the `Foo` class's `some_function()` method.

I can also over-ride the `__init__()` method and set the `_some_condition` as an instance attribute. Like so **(Here, we are using an instance attribute)**:

```
class Bar(models.Model):
    ...

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Bar, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._some_condition = False # Instance attribute

    ...
```

What even is the difference between the two? I'm generally confused about class and instance attributes in Python.

After doing it both ways for the same model, and testing it in the shell, it seems there is no difference at all between class attributes and instance attributes. Can anyone explain this? The following is the code I used to test both ways:

```
class MyClass(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    _class_attr = ''

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyClass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._instance_attr = ''

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Update both before saving
        self._class_attr = 'Class attribute'
        self._instance_attr = 'Instance attribute'
        super(MyClass, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Results:

```
>>> from myapp.models import MyClass
>>> MyClass.objects.create(name='first')
<MyClass: MyClass object (1)>
>>> MyClass.objects.create(name='second')
<MyClass: MyClass object (2)>
>>> first = MyClass.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> second = MyClass.objects.get(pk=2)
>>> first._class_attr
''
>>> first._instance_attr
''
>>> second._class_attr
''
>>> second._instance_attr
''
>>> first.save()
>>> first._class_attr
'Class attribute'
>>> first._instance_attr
'Instance attribute'
>>> second._class_attr
''
>>> second._instance_attr
''
```

Comment: How are you going to use this attribute? Does it need to be persisted between requests?

Comment: It needs to persist between different class methods that run before the save method. It basically makes my life easier as this way, the code is organized really nicely.